# How do I get the file path from my ActionMailer?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I'm developing a Rails 3 application, and I currently I would like to add an image as an attachment into an email.

I'm doing the following right now:

```
class CouponMailer < ActionMailer::Base
  default :from => "name@domain.com", :content_type => "multipart/mixed"

  def send_coupon(recipient, coupon)
    @coupon = coupon
    @recipient = recipient

    attachments.inline["#{coupon.picture.title}"] = File.read(File.join(root_url, coupon.picture.url))

    mail(:to => recipient.email, :subject => "a subject")
  end
end
```

The image I want has been uploaded from my [RefineryCMS](http://refinerycms.com) application, and when I copy the url that I get when I do `File.join(root_url, coupon.picture.url)` and paste it in the browser, I can see the imagen, but when I run the application I get the following error:

```
No such file or directory - http://localhost:3000/system/images/BAhbBlsHOgZmIiwyMDExLzA1LzI0LzE3XzQ4XzUxXzcxNF9tYWluX2ltYWdlMi5qcGc/main_image2.jpg
```

Any ideas?

Comment: I am not sure you can read in files from urls.

Comment: And how do I get the physical path of the image in a neat way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like RefineryCMS is using [Dragonfly](https://github.com/markevans/dragonfly) for file uploads. I believe you want to call .path on your picture to retrieve a file system path. Probably something like so:

```
attachments.inline["#{coupon.picture.title}"] = File.read(coupon.picture.file)
```

Have a look at the [documentation](http://markevans.github.com/dragonfly/) for more info. You should find what you need on the [General Usage](http://markevans.github.com/dragonfly/file.GeneralUsage.html) page.

Comment: No problem - I've fought with Dragonfly before and know your pain!